# How to Stop Handlebars from Executing String?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How can I make it so that I can write my javascript handlebar expression as a string and it won't execute?

I'm trying to do:

```
let plainFormat = '${{amount}}';
console.log(plainFormat, "plainFormat");
```

Comment: If i execute the code i get `${{amount}} plainFormat` logged. is that the desired result?

Comment: [Escaping Handlebars expression](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#escaping-handlebars-expressions) could help. In your case `let plainFormat = '$\{{amount}}';`

Comment: The desired results is the when logged the text would be ${{amount}} as a string

Comment: let plainFormat = '$\{{amount}}'; didn't work

Comment: Mm idk then, it worked here: https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22let%20plainFormat%20%3D%20'%24%5C%5C%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D'%3B%5Cnconsole.log(plainFormat%2C%20%5C%22plainFormat%5C%22)%3B%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22null%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22let%20plainFormat%20%3D%20'%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D'%3B%5Cnconsole.log(plainFormat%2C%20%5C%22plainFormat%5C%22)%3B%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.3%22%7D  (the {{{{raw}}}} thing did not work, no clue)